# C++ 2d array created by double pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to create 2d array using pointer and show then show it. I change rows by increment pointer (one *) and columns by index.
My code:

```
int ** tabl=new int *[4];
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    tabl[i]=new int [3];
int **ptab=tabl;//save first position of array

for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        *tabl[j]=rand()%10 +1;
        printf("%4d",*tabl[j]);
    }
    tabl++;
}
tabl=ptab;
cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%4d",*tabl[j]);
    }
    tabl++;
}
```

Output:

```
   2   8   5   1  10   5   9   9   3   5   6   6

   2   1   9   1   9   5   9   5   6   5   6   6
```

But some of the digits in the second loop are different then the original. Why?

Comment: `*tabl[j]` means `tabl[j][0]`. You actually wanted `tabl[0][j]`.  It would be better to use `tabl[i][j]` instead, and not do `tabl++`, and not have `ptab`.

Comment: I know two index method, but my teacher from studies demand using pointers.

Comment: This does use pointers. When you write `tabl[i]`, actually `tabl` decays to a pointer, and the code is defined as being equivalent to `*(tabl+i)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the way you refer to the element. It should be `(*tabl)[j]`, not `*tabl[j]`.

Also note that you go beyound allocated memory here:

```
int ** tabl=new int *[4];
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
               ^
    -----------+
```

Comment: I changed size from 10 to 4, because I really didn't see all values, that's why "10" left(I missed it). Of course I corrected it. I understand the brackets are there because of the priorities?

Comment: Yes, `*tabl[j]` means "dereference j-th element of tabl", not "j-th element of dereferenced table"